# $\|X\|=\|F(X)\|$ and the inner product ex

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $X=(x,y)$ amf let $F$ ne a rotation through an angle $\theta$. Show that $\|X\|=\|F(X)\|$ (i.e preserves norms).

The norm of X is given by $\|X\|=\langle X,X\rangle=\langle\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\rangle^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

If I consider the $X´=\begin{bmatrix}x´\\y´\end{bmatrix}$ the coordinate point after an angle $\theta$ rotation. Then:

$$\begin{align}\|X´\|&=\left\|\begin{bmatrix}x´\\y´\end{bmatrix}\right\|\\&=\left\|\begin{bmatrix}x\cos(\theta)-y\sin(\theta)\\x\sin(\theta)+y\cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}\right\|\\
&=\left\langle\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&\cos{\theta}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&\cos{\theta}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} \right\rangle^{\frac{1}{2}}\\&=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\:\:\:\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

I would like to know if the inner product allows for such operations that I performed once the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&\cos{\theta}\end{bmatrix}$ can be considered a constant.

**Question:**

**1)** Is the answer I provided to the question right? Does it comply with the inner product properties?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your proof of the fact that your map preserves norms is correct. But I don't understand what you mean by “the matrix [...] can be considered a constant”. And I also don't understand why there is a question no. 1 but there are no other questions.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos Thanks for the reply. I was thinking of the matrix coming out of the inner product. It was only fear I was violating any inner product property. I have just numbered the question out of habit, but there are no more questions. Anyway now I know my answer is right!

Comment: Write out your expression in detail and apply basic trig identities, and your answer should be sefl-evident.

Comment: Your very last "$=$" is not sufficiently justified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote is correct, but it is not clear from where  it comes  the result $||X'||=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=||X||$ .

It is better to calculate explicitly:
$$
\left \langle\begin{bmatrix}x\cos(\theta)-y\sin(\theta)\\x\sin(\theta)+y\cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}x\cos(\theta)-y\sin(\theta)\\x\sin(\theta)+y\cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle^{\frac{1}{2}}= \left[(x\cos(\theta)-y\sin(\theta))^2+(x\cos(\theta)+y\sin(\theta))^2 \right]^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$

and use $\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)=1$ to find the result.